# I want to add a button in a paging grid column and register a separate event for the button.Gwt

Tags: gwt, grid, gxt

I'm having a paging grid in which i have a column of buttons. Can i add a separate button click handler apart from the row click handler?

I'm using this code, but its not working

```
ColumnConfig<Stock, String> buttonCol = new ColumnConfig<Stock, String>(
            props.button(), 100, "Button");

    TextButtonCell edit=new TextButtonCell();



    edit.setText("Edit");
    buttonCol.setCell(edit);
    edit.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
            Window w=new Window();
            w.setHeadingText("Test Popup");
            VerticalPanel vp12345=new  VerticalPanel();
            vp12345.add(new TextField());
            vp12345.add(new Button("transfer"));
            vp12345.add(new Button("Exit"));

            w.add(vp12345);


            w.show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly " not working"?

Comment: If i click the button the entire row is selected.But i particularly want an event on a button click.Now the entire row is being selected on click of the button in the button column

Comment: Could you place code of whole class here?

Comment: Sorry Mike, i'm restricted from doing that.But i'm using a paging grid in which i have a column of buttons.I have a select handler on the grid which is getting triggered even on the button click.I have a separate handler on the button in the column as in the above code.

Comment: Don't know what to say. According to example https://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:cellgrid  you're making it all right. Probably some issue in 'GridView' or 'SelectionModel'.